# Laravel 5.2 : Restrict routes for guest and auth

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want to let guest access this route :

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['guest']], function () {
    Route::get('explore', 'FormController@formsList');
});
```

But I also want people who are artist to access this route but not the `labels` :

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'],function()
{

    Route::group(['middleware' => 'isLabel'],function()
    {

    });

    Route::group(['middleware' => 'isArtist'],function()
    {
        Route::get('explore', 'FormController@formsList');
    });

});
```

The thing is that `guests` can't access the route but `artists` can and it's not what I want.

Label middleware

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (!Auth::guest() && Auth::user()->type->idtype ===1) {
            return $next($request);

        }
        return redirect('/');

    }
```

Artist Middleware

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (!Auth::guest() && Auth::user()->type->idtype ===2) {
            return $next($request);

        }
        return redirect('/');

    }
```

Comment: Show us your middlewares you've created

Comment: Just updated my question

Comment: So,  Artists *and* guests should be able to visit the explore route?

Comment: @manniL Yes exactly but not the label.

Comment: @manniL your question is not super clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot "define" or group a route twice. That's why your current code does not work

I'd suggest creating a new middleware called `ArtistAndGuestMiddleware` where you define that guests and artists can pass.

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (Auth::guest() || Auth::user()->type->idtype ===2 ) {
            return $next($request);

        }
        return redirect('/');

    }
```